# JPA Entity not registered with EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, guice

I've been implementing a modular architecture application using Guice, with each application module separated into individual eclipse projects and having it's own Guice module. I've been getting problems with registering JPA entities that are not on the JPA persistence project. The ones inside the project are registered without a problem, but the ones on the other projects are not. There was no problem while the application was implemented on a single project and single Guice module.

The configurations appear to be ok, but most likely there's something I'm missing.
This is error I get when trying to get an entity from the database:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class org.gradle.security.persistence.jpa.entities.impl.SubjectImpl
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:203)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:139)
at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:173)
at org.gradle.security.pbeingersistence.jpa.dao.impl.SubjectDAOImpl.findByPrincipal(SubjectDAOImpl.java:48)
```

with the SubjectDAOImpl below and the error when trying to get the entity on the last line,

```
    public Subject findByPrincipal(String principal, LockModeType lockMode) {
    CriteriaQuery<SubjectImpl> criteria = criteriaQuery(SubjectImpl.class);
    CriteriaBuilder cb = getEM().getCriteriaBuilder();

    Root<SubjectImpl> activation = criteria.from(SubjectImpl.class);
    ....
```

with SubjectImpl being:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name=SubjectImpl.TABLE_NAME, schema=Config.Schemas.DEFAULT)
public class SubjectImpl extends BaseEntityImpl implements Subject {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = Config.TABLE_PREFIX + "subject";

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "principal", unique = true)
    protected String principal;
    ......
}
```

The Guice modules are configured as follows:

Security Module:

```
private static class SecurityModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Subject.class).to(SubjectImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
        ...
        bind(SubjectDAO.class).to(SubjectDAOImpl.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

Persistence Module:

```
public class JPAPersistenceModule extends AbstractModule implements ArchetypeModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(
                this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(PersistenceProperties.DEFAULT_PROPERTIES_FILE).getPath());
        props.load(is);
        Names.bindProperties(binder(), props);

        bind(PersistenceProperties.class).asEagerSingleton();
        JpaPersistModule persistModule = new JpaPersistModule(PersistenceProperties.PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
        persistModule.properties(props);
        install(persistModule);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not load persistence module: ", e);
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

And the server module:

```
public class ServerModule extends JerseyServletModule implements ArchetypeModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
        filter("/*").through(PersistFilter.class);
        serve("/rest","/rest/*").with(GuiceContainer.class);
    }
}
```

The Guice modules are installed by this order: JPAPersistenceModule, SecurityModule, ServerModule.
Can't get my head around the problem, can you give me a hand?

Comment: Why not start from working example?

Comment: Are you refering to Guice JPA working example? Just now noticed that the word "multi-module" I used is a bit confusing because of Guice modules. I'm implementing a modular application architecture, where each guice module on its own separate eclipse project. I'll edit that avoid confusion. While on a single project and single guice module everything worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to a friend who implemented a project using the same architecture and similar technology I came to find out that the cause is due to a JPA Hibernate limitation. Unlike many other annotations, the annotations of the JPA implementation can only be detected on the project that implement the Guice persistence module.

A workaround for this issue is to capture all the classes with the annotation using reflection ([Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library does this for you) and pass it on to the Guice JpaPersistModule on the properties argument.
The result should be somewhat similar to this:

```
props.put(org.hibernate.jpa.AvailableSettings.LOADED_CLASSES, Lists.newArrayList(EntityLoader.loadEntities()));

JpaPersistModule persistModule = new JpaPersistModule(PersistenceProperties.PERSISTENCE_UNIT);
persistModule.properties(props);
install(persistModule);
```